# How to show group by in mysql?

Tags: mysql, database

Suppose i have the table with different number of dogs.

```
---------------------------------
| ID |       NAME         |Number|
---------------------------------
|  1 | German Shephard    |3     |
---------------------------------
|  2 | Bull Dog           |5     |
---------------------------------  
|3   | Pug                |7     |
```

They belong to all Supert set of Dog species.Now i want to show the total sum by renaming them as Dog Species.How to do in mysql?

```
---------------------------------
| ID |       NAME         |Sum|
---------------------------------
|  1 |Dog species         |15   |
---------------------------------
```

Comment: Have you [**tried anything**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) so far?

Comment: Are there any other types of furry animals here besides dogs, cats maybe?

Comment: yes i have used substring but this is normal example since my datas are latge i am not getting correct result

Comment: I have just given a example here, but my datas being large i get incorrect answer so i want to see from this simple example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the following query:

```
SELECT 1 AS ID, 'Dog species' AS NAME, SUM(Number) AS Sum
FROM yourTable;
```

This is a bit contrived, and ideally your table would have another column corresponding to the species.  Then, we could `GROUP BY` this column, and report sums for each species.

Comment: yes, I didn't see any column referring to the `superset` in his given structure.